# ANTLR extraneous input when using words already defined

Tags: antlr

I'm facing a problem with what looks like simple grammar:

```
grammar Test;

init :
    init separator init
    | word;

word :
    ( LETTER )+ ;

separator :
    SPACE OPERATOR SPACE
    | SPACE ;

SPACE : ' '+ ;
LETTER : 'A'..'Z' ;
OPERATOR : 'AND' | 'OR' ;

WS : [\t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

If I input the string **AOR OR B** what I get is an **line 1:1 extraneous input 'OR' expecting {, SPACE, LETTER}** but I don't understand why, because the word should match any capital letter until find a space char, isn't it?

The result what I expect is to catch the word AOR, the OR operator and the word B.

Can anyone give me some tips?, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the input `AOR OR B` gets tokenized as follows:

1. type=`WORD`, text=`A`
2. type=`OR`, text=`OR`
3. type=`SPACE`, text=
4. type=`OR`, text=`OR`
5. type=`SPACE`, text=
6. type=`WORD`, text=`B`

If you want `AOR` to be tokenized as a single word, you should make it a lexer rule instead of a parser rule:

```
WORD : 'A'..'Z'+ ;
```

Comment: why does OPERATOR take precedence over LETTER? shouldn't it be the other way, being LETTER first in the definition?

Comment: @1010 because the lexer tries to match as much characters as possible. Only when two rules match the same amount of characters, the rule defined first will *win*.

Answer (score 0):

- don't mix lexical and syntax analysis. word should be a token, the way you defined it with a grammar rule allows WS to appear inside a word.
- why is `' '` different from `\t \r \n`? has it a special meaning for your grammar?
  if you define WS as `[ \t\r\n] -> skip` your tokens will be separated by those chars, and they will be ignored.
- use an unambigous grammar. parser generators may resolve ambigouities but the correctness of the result will depend on the grammar and the tool you use. you must know how the generator resolves it.

  ```
  init : init separator init | word
  ```

  can be equivalently and unambigously expressed as

  ```
  init : word init2;
  init2 : separator word init2 | ;
  ```

  or

  ```
  init : word (separator word)*
  ```